# Finding out which of the following inequalities involving expectation is invalid

Tags: calculus, optimization, expected-value, jensen-inequality

I want to figure out which of the below is not necessarily correct. We have

(1)
$$
E[|x|] \geq |E[x]|
$$

This is always correct due to Jensen's inequality and the absolute value function being a convex function.

(2)
$$
E[x^4] \geq E[x]^4
$$

The function $f(x) = x^4$ is convex because $f"(x) = 12x^2 \geq 0$. So this is always correct as well by Jensen's inequality.

(3)
$$
E[x^2] \geq E[|x|]
$$

I don't know how to formally justify this because if I plot $x^2$ vs $|x|$ in my mind, then it's clear (visually) that $E[x^2] < E[|x|]$ if $x \in [0, 1]$. So this one is not always correct. How can I justify this mathematically or is what I stated sufficient justification?

(4)
$$
E[\exp x] \geq 1 + E[x]
$$

For this one, I think we just simply do a taylor series expansion of $\exp x$ about $x = 0$ and then apply linearity of expectation. So
$$
\exp x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} + \ldots \\
\implies \exp x \geq 1 + x \\
\implies E[\exp x] \geq 1 + E[x]
$$
Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, that the third one is the one that's not always true; your reasoning is solid too: To get a counterexample take $X$ to be a random variable such that $P(X=1/2)=1$ for instance.

For the last one, I'd just say an extra word about why this works when $x\leq 0$.

Comment: Ah so for that example on the 3rd problem, you defined $X$ to essentially be a constant random variable? For the last one, why do I need to say anything for $x \leq 0$? I think my proof doesn't depend on if $x > 0$ or not?

Comment: @student010101: $x^3\leq 0$ and in fact, for $x<<0$ we have that $x^2/2+x^3/6 <<0$, so it needs a bit more (convexity to be precise, since the inequality is saying the exponential is above the tangent line at $x=0$).

Comment: I think for the negative $x$ case we only care about the situation where $-1 < x$ because if $x < -1$, then it is clear that $x^2 / 2 + x^3 / 6 + \ldots < 0$?

Comment: @student010101: Sure, but a word or two need to be said in my opinion.